# Order Status - PayPal - Payment review auto-change to completed

Tags: paypal

I am facing a issue about an order using PayPal as the payment method.

This order was instantly set to "completed" after placed the order, which should become "payment review" only.

Below is the message about the order. Is there any setting I can change?

> Jun 10, 2016 5:30:27 PM|Complete
>   Customer Notified
>   Jun 10, 2016 5:30:27 PM|Payment Review
>   Customer Notification Not Applicable 
>   Capturing amount of $69.89 is pending approval on gateway. Transaction ID: